# warning NU1701: Package 'System.Linq.Queryable 4.0.1' was restored using '.NETFramework,V ersion=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I always got the following warning when creating a new .net core project. How to fix the issue?

```
PS C:\TEMP\t> dotnet new webapi -o test2
The template "ASP.NET Core Web API" was created successfully.

Processing post-creation actions...
Running 'dotnet restore' on test2\test2.csproj...
  Restoring packages for C:\TEMP\t\test2\test2.csproj...
C:\TEMP\t\test2\test2.csproj : warning NU1701: Package 'System.Linq.Queryable 4.0.1' was restored using '.NETFramework,V
ersion=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1'. This package may not be fully compati
ble with your project.
  Generating MSBuild file C:\TEMP\t\test2\obj\test2.csproj.nuget.g.props.
  Generating MSBuild file C:\TEMP\t\test2\obj\test2.csproj.nuget.g.targets.
  Restore completed in 1.42 sec for C:\TEMP\t\test2\test2.csproj.

Restore succeeded.
```

Comment: I believe it's because you don't have .net v2.1 installed, so it's warning you that it's using a new version rather than the one the project is targeting.

Comment: I have .Net v2.1 installed.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the package `System.Linq.Queryable` and install package for you project target framework.